# Django login without authenticating

Tags: django

I have a Django app where there are 2 use cases where I want a user to be able to login without a password.

1. User registers and gets activation link in e-mail.
2. User resets password and gets link to change password form in e-mail.

The links include a one-time-use key that I validate, and then I want to log the user in without using credentials.

```
# This raises an exception unless
# I call user.authenticate 1st.
auth.login(request, user)
```

How do I acheive this?

Comment: Technically those two use cases also apply authentication, just by other means: namely the unique token that you include in the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own authentication backend(s) which handles your two use cases. See the docs on writing and using a custom auth backend:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources

EDIT:
There seems there might be some misconception about how difficult it might be to write your own auth backend. From the docs:

> An authentication backend is a class
> that implements two methods:
> get_user(user_id) and
> authenticate(**credentials).

That's right. It's any class that implements two functions both which return `User` objects.

> The get_user method takes a user_id --
> which could be a username, database ID
> or whatever -- and returns a User
> object.
>
> ...authenticate should check the
> credentials it gets, and it should
> return a User object that matches
> those credentials, if the credentials
> are valid. If they're not valid, it
> should return None.

The OP has already stated that the links contain one-time keys that he validates (and presumably has associated with the user he wishes to log in). In other words he's already written the business logic for the backend, he would just need to convert it into an appropirate class.

Custom authentication backends can do a number of awesome things in Django 1.2 like object level permissions but they don't have to be that complicated. Plus they stack so you can mix in your token based authentication with the default model backend or OpenID or Facebook. But in the end an auth backend is just class with two methods and I don't see how you can call that overkill.

Comment: Are you serious? This is not a case for writing your own backend! If he'd like to use ie. OpenID or authentication from other sources - that's OK, but not in this case - it would be overkill!

Comment: "The links include a one-time-use key that I validate" He's basically doing token based authentication now which is a perfect use case for your own auth backend.

Comment: I like this idea, but there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a backend when calling authenticate(). I don't want to add the token backend to settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND, because the authentication waterfall is not appropriate. I only want to authenticate against the token backend. I guess I will manually instantiate the token backend, do the authentication, and then set user.backend manually as described in rekmulk's answer.

Comment: I'm in the midst of implementing a site in Django, and have tried both the manually-set-backend-and-login method as well as the token-based auth backend method. While both of them have merit and both ultimately work, the auth backend isn't a lot of work to implement (configuration items aside, it was as many lines as the manual method inside the view, or thereabouts), and it has the advantage of conforming with the patterns of the rest of Django.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the method described [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login) in the Django docs. You grab your user based on the one-time-use key you supplied them and call login(request, user). The catch here is that you'll need to manually specify the authentication backend because you're not calling authenticate() first.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def my_view(request):

    // your user retrieval code
    ...

    user.backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    login(request, user)
```

Comment: I did this way, but don't know why, in later XHR request, Django set session-id in the cookie to blank string, thus make user logout. Can you tell me why?

Comment: I wish I could. I haven't worked with Django in several years now so I'm a bit out of touch with things.

Answer (score 4):

Here you have working snippet that logins user without requiring credentials.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1547/

Answer (score 1):

Look at [django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) app, it's exactly what you need :)

**Edit:**

New link to the [django-registration repo](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration)

Comment: The repo doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @AliBZ, as you can see this post was from 2010 (6 years ago!) - non-existing repo is not a reason to downvote... Just comment with the new link and don't be a d*ck :) Especially that the old link tells you where to go - just learn how to read: https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration ... I updated the answer now.

Comment: I am a d*ck so I won't remove my downvote! Just kidding ;) Thanks for the new link.

Comment: I didn't see the the new link on the bitbucket page. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ska` package, which has password-less login to Django implemented. `ska` works with authentication tokens and its' security is based on SHARED_KEY which should be equal for all parties (servers) envolved.

On client side (party that requests a passsword-less login), you generate a URL and sign it, using `ska`. Example:

```
from ska import sign_url
from ska.contrib.django.ska.settings import SECRET_KEY

server_ska_login_url = 'https://server-url.com/ska/login/'

signed_url = sign_url(
    auth_user = 'test_ska_user_0',
    secret_key = SECRET_KEY,
    url = server_ska_login_url
    extra = {
        'email': 'john.doe@mail.example.com',
        'first_name': 'John',
        'last_name': 'Doe',
    }
    )
```

Default lifetime of the token is 600 seconds. You can customise that by proving a `lifetime` argument.

On the server side (site to which users' log in), having in mind that you have installed `ska` properly, the user
is logged in upon visiting the URL if they existed (username match), or otherwise - created.  There are 3 callbacks that you can customise in your project's Django settings.

USER_GET_CALLBACK (string): Fired if user was successfully fetched from database (existing user).
USER_CREATE_CALLBACK (string): Fired right after user has been created (user didn't exist).
USER_INFO_CALLBACK (string): Fired upon successful authentication.

See the documentation (http://pythonhosted.org/ska/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that either of those cases should count as a "login".  They should be handled as a special case, via views that don't require authentication.

Comment: That's probably a better idea for the 2nd case I have listed, but for the 1st case I would like the user to be automatically logged in once they have clicked the activate link. I can't think of any good reason to make them enter their user name and password again after activating.